# Is it acceptable to bring items from former employer to work?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, ethics

I have mugs, coasters, etc. from previous employers that I enjoy using, but am hesitant about bringing them to work at my current employer because they're branded with former employer's logo. Will it seem like Coke vs. Pepsi if I bring those in? What if they're not exactly competitors, or even in the same industry?

What about achievement plaques/awards? On one hand, they're a testament to your expertise and experience, but may be perceived by your current colleagues as pretentious.

Comment: Do you have space for all this?

Comment: Not that many. Mug and coaster don't take up that much space, and they're just on my desk. We have shelves/cabinets for books and other personal items that I could use for plaques (just two or so for Length of Service and Project Achievement). Space is irrelevant... would a new executive place awards from former employer in his/her office? That's what I would like to know.

Comment: Every place I've been, this type of corporate swag is considered a sort of minor trophy to indicate seniority, like, "hey look Bob worked at IBM in 1990" or similar. Often they come with stories. I've never seen a negative reaction.

Comment: Curious why the downvote... I see colleagues wearing shirts from previous employers to work all the time. Just extending this to personal items.

Comment: @PeteW That's what I thought too.

Comment: (referring to the mugs and t-shirts as the swag, not the awards, just to be clear. nothing wrong with either)

Comment: If you see other people wearing previous employers shirts to work, then it sounds like a mug or coaster is fine.

Comment: Doesn't your day-to-day work speak enough about your expertise and/or experience? I mean, I've met a lot of people through my career, some of them were very good, I couldn't care less about their previous achievements or awards, or the lack of it, as long as they show and use these skills to achieve great results.

Comment: Based on the comments and answers, the consensus is that it depends on the message these "swags" are sending to one's current colleagues and employer. Items of utility are fine unless the branding or message is inappropriate in the context of current workplace. Awards and other branded decorative items from former employers do not belong at the current employer.

Comment: The simple answer is **NO**.  It would be absurd, if not laughable, to bring in "mugs" from any previous companies.  Regarding bringing "awards" - it's so silly, just forget the idea.

Answer (score 8):

If you have certificates, awards, and souvenirs that are industry wide rather than specific to your employer, by all means bring them to work. That mug a podcast sent you after you appeared? That certificate you earned after 6 months of studying and a seven-hour exam? Absolutely, they belong in your office.

Things that have only the logo of your former employer, or make sense only in that context (an award for fewest bugs or a plaque that you get when a customer sends a testimonial about you) -- leave them at home and use them when you want to reminisce about the place you used to work. You don't have to hate that place forever, it's great that you like it, but you don't work there any more, so those things don't belong in your office at work.

Comment: I feel it might be advisable to make this clear / shorter for the OP.  As in "forget this silly idea"  :/

Answer (score 6):

> I have mugs, coasters, etc. from previous employers that I enjoy using

It's a mug. It's not that important. Find a new mug.

> may be perceived by your current colleagues as pretentious.

That'll be because it is pretentious. I don't care what you did at your previous employer, I care that you're productive in your new role.

Realistically, are these things *that* important to you that you're preparing to risk alienating your new colleagues? If not, you know the answer to your question already.

Comment: Yeah, I'd leave them at home, might have my certifications at work, but only if asked.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. You're right, it's just a mug I could just get another; It's also just a mug that they couldn't care less what's printed on it - goes both ways. Though to avoid potential awkwardness in the workplace, your suggestion is valid.

Comment: @DaveH., To tell you the truth, the mugs are fine (unless it's a direct competitor), but to me, since you brought them up at the same time you brought up your awards, it sounds to me like you see them in the same light, and that you're actually proud of your former company, which is fine. Just keep it low-key, a mug or two is fine, but don't over do it with too many objects from your former employer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Nobody cares about utility things.

There are exceptions, but generally?  Nobody's going to care whether your coffee mug says "Some Random Prior Company", "Coding Fuel Within", or "Worlds Greatest Dad".  It's a mug - you use it to drink coffee from.

Same thing with most utilitarian items.  General rule of thumb: if it's not a competitor, and it's not clothing (which sort of marks you as an employee of the prior company) it's fine.

#### Nobody cares about your past awards from another company

However, that doesn't mean you should display these.  It's because it's the equivalent of a 27 year old bragging about their SAT score: it comes across a bit 'braggy' and the time that it actually mattered has passed.  Nobody cares whether you earned "Programmer of the Month" from your past job.  It was relevant when you were applying for the job to begin with, but not for what you're doing now.